# Postgres pg_hba.conf: ip range not working

Tags: postgresql, docker, ip-address

I have multiple Docker containers running, IP range is from 172.17.0.1 to 172.17.0.5. I have Postgres installed on the host,  so I added `host  all     all     172.17.0.0/16       trust` to pg_hba.conf. My Docker containers still can't access the host database.

However, if I use `host all     all     0.0.0.0/0       trust`, everythig work fine, but I don't want to open my database to all ip addresses.

Also, 172.17.0.0/16 means IP range from 172.17.0.0 to 172.17.255.255 at http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16           trust
```

Comment: If you need only five addresses, you could to enumerate its explicitly, line by line: `172.17.0.1/32`, `172.17.0.2/32` etc.

Comment: Set `log_connections` to `on` and see the error message in the PostgreSQL log. Maybe it uses a different IP address?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54640591/770473