# Docker postgres image: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a Docker image for DB (postgres is installed) and I try to run it but I get the following:

> db             | 2018-11-27 08:29:28.849 UTC [2808] FATAL:  no
>   pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.x.x.x", user "postgres", database
>   "postgres", SSL off

I tried the following:

- To change the IP and put my current machine's ip
- When setting up Postgres: `echo -e "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust"` I put that

None of those work.

Comment: Could you post your `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem getting my application container to talk to my postgres container. I fixed this with three steps:

1. define the network ip address range for the docker network

```
# +----------------------+
# |  docker-compose.yml  |
# +----------------------+
networks:
  my_docker_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

2. whitelist the same network ip address range in the postgres pg_hba.conf file

```
# +---------------+
# |  pg_hba.conf  |
# +---------------+
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             10.5.0.0/16             trust
```

I used `trust` to avoid authentication hassles, but you could specify `md5`, `cert`, or any other valid authentication method.

3. allow postgres to listen to external hosts in the postgresql.conf file

```
# +-------------------+
# |  postgresql.conf  |
# +-------------------+
# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Comment: why are you manually modifying configs with docker??? why not pass commands or envs to automate changes when container is started???